# Usage of Dative + sein sentence construction

Tags: sentence-structure, dative

For one of my sentences, a native German speaker corrected it to be a “dative + sein” construction.

Original:  Wenn es nur wahr wäre.

Suggestion:  Wenn dem nur so wäre!

They proposed that the suggested structure was more elegant and gave a second example:

Original:  Das war nicht aber so.

Suggestion:  Dem war nicht aber so.

Can someone please tell me what the underlying grammar rule is for the “dative + sein” structure and whether it applies to other combinations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Wenn **es** nur so wäre! — **Es** war aber nicht so.
>
> Wenn **das** nur so wäre! — **Das** war aber nicht so.

These are both perfectly okay. The latter has a pointing finger to the thing in question.

> Wenn **dem** nur so wäre! — **Dem** war aber nicht so.

This is an idiom, **dem ist so**, which is in wide use. *Sein+Dativ* is in Grimms' grammar, so it's not *ungrammatical* but it doesn't fit any system. I can't think of any other use either.

Comment: One might add that *Dem ist nicht so* sounds a little bit more educated and unobtrusive or polite, whereas *Das ist nicht so* sounds very plain or even a bit rough.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the situations where it would be appropriate to use this idiom? Only together with a negation or conjunctive?

Comment: It's a drop-in replacement for *das ist so* for all forms of *sein*. No further restrictions.

Comment: "Ist das wahr? - Ja, dem ist so!"  Would this use be correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Janka: Ist es Absicht, dass du an 3 Stellen _»nicht aber«_ stehen hast statt _»aber nicht«_?

Comment: Das habe ich falsch aus der Frage kopiert. Danke für den Hinweis.

Comment: What about "Mir ist schlecht", "Wie geht es dir?", usw.? Also in Grimm's grammar.

Comment: That's different because it's a real **wem?** you can ask for. In the phrase *dem ist so*, you ask *was?* and answer *dem*. That would be ungrammatical if it wasn't already written down as a special case.

Answer (score 3):

As Janka says, this construction is correct and widely used.

It should be noted, however, that "dem ist so" can sound formal to the degree of stiltedness in many contexts. I've rarely heard it in normal conversation -- and then usually in an ironic context.

For a non-native, I'd say it is safer to stick to the less elegant but much more common versions:

> Das ist so.
>   Es ist so.
>   Es ist wahr.
>   etc.